# EF not retrieving entity out of context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What I'd like to happen is that if I've already created the record (`GuildName`) in the session and attached it to the context,then for EF to retrieve it from the context instead of creating a duplicate, however it cant seam to make it not create a duplicate.

```
public static async Task ProcessNames()
{
    var db = new SQLDbContext();
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    var existingNames = db.CharacterNames.Include("GuildName").Include("RealmName").Take(10).ToList();
    var gatherGuildNameTaskList = (
           from name in existingNames 
           select GetGuildFromName(name, db)).ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll(gatherGuildNameTaskList);
    db.SaveChanges();
}


public static async Task GetGuildFromName(CharacterName characterName, SQLDbContext db)
{
    var character = await ApiHelper.GetJsonFromUrlAsync<Character>(new Uri( URL ));
    if (character.Guild == null) return;

    //This is the call that appears to not be working as intended
    var guildName = db.GuildName.
        SingleOrDefault(x => x.RealmName.Name == character.Guild.Name) ?? new GuildName
    {
        Name = character.Guild.Name,
        CharacterNames = new List<CharacterName>(),
        RealmName = characterName.RealmName
    };

    if (!guildName.Equals(characterName.GuildName))
    {
        characterName.GuildName = guildName;
    }
}
```

I only having it take 10 names for testing, but normally there's a few 100k's

The only thing I can think is to call save changes on search method of `GetGuildFromName`, but I have a feeling, that it might not work as intended, but could be detrimental to performance, not that performance is a huge factor, but I like trying to practice making things perform reasonably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you never add your newGuildName to the context (        db.GuildName.Add(guildName) like this:

```
var guildName = db.GuildName.
        SingleOrDefault(x => x.RealmName.Name == character.Guild.Name);
if (guildName ==null)
{ 
    guildName = new GuildName
       {
        Name = character.Guild.Name,
        CharacterNames = new List<CharacterName>(),
        RealmName = characterName.RealmName
       };
    db.GuildName.Add(guildName);
}
```

Comment: This was it, I thought by adding it to the character that it would attach itself to the context, it dosent save to the db when doing this but apparently not to the context for lookup